# ¿Qué significa "desacomplejado"?

Tags: traducción, significado, adjetivos

¿Qué significa "desacomplejado" en este contexto en inglés?

> Y emerge otro Canadá. Un país que mira menos a Europa y más a Asia. Un país donde la explosión del petróleo ha alterado los equilibrios económicos y el poder se ha desplazado a las provincias del Oeste, más cercanas culturalmente a Estados Unidos. Más **desacomplejado** y menos atado al multilateralismo, seña de identidad de la política exterior canadiense en el siglo XX.

Pueden encontrar el texto completo en el siguiente enlace: http://elpais.com/internacional/2014/09/20/actualidad/1411236740_706033.html

A pesar de haber leído los diccionarios, no he encontrado nada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trátase en *desacomplejado* de una palabra base con un afijo — en este caso un prefijo.  Los diccionarios no suelen incluir las palabras con afijos, ya que su significado debe ser fácil de determinar modificando el significado de la palabra base con el del afijo, a menos que su significado sea diferente del esperado.

En este case, tenemos la palabra base *acomplejado*<sup>1</sup>:

> **acomplejado** 1. *adj.* Que padece complejos psíquicos

y el prefijo *des-*:

> **des-** 1. *pref.* Denota negación o inversión del significado del simple. *Desconfiar, deshacer.*

Entonces, el significado sería la inversión («ya no...») del sufrimiento de tales trastornos, «Que ya no padece complejos psíquicos».  En inglés, que sepa, no hay ninguna palabra sencilla para referir a la idea, pero una traducción posible podría ser “Less complexes [insert the one you feel best, little-man syndrome, identity-crisis] and less attachment to multilateralism, signs of …”

---

<sup>1. En el DRAE, no aparece ninguna acepción como «hecho más complejo» porque, como mencioné, es un significado transparente al que se puede llegar añadiendo el sufijo *-ado* al verbo *acomplejar* que, en su caso, podría significar «hacer más complejo» pero no está registrado porque, otra vez, no hay problema en entenderlo por los componentes.  Las acepciones registradas no refieren a hacer complejo alguna cosa, sino de causar o inducir complejos, relacionado sí pero tampoco «esperado» (por eso está incluida como palabra aparte).</sup>

Comment: ¿significa 'sane' o 'mentally well'? En contexto, Canadá es 'less crazy' ¿verdad?

Comment: @TheSquareCow Sí, pero específicamente después de haber sufrido problemas psíquicos.  I don't think *crazy* quite works though, *acomplejado* refers more to particular manias than anything.  Probably "More sure of itself" would be a good translation.

Answer (score 2):

Los *complejos* serían no tanto una enfermedad mental grave, sino más bien "complejos de inferioridad", diversos pensamientos de que uno mismo es "inferior" o "peor" que otro, o incluso añadiendo un matiz de timidez. Otra forma de verlo, es que uno mismo se autolimita.

Como ese "complejo de inferioridad" o timidez muchas veces se traduce en un retraimiento y en un menor grado de actividad, **desacomplejado** significa que no existen esos complejos, y se actua de forma mucho más decidida, sin verguenza. No existe ninguna autolimitación.

En el texto que suscita la pregunta, dice que Canadá durante el siglo XX ha actuado a nivel internacional, de forma limitada y principalmente de forma multinacional (Canadá actuaba en concierto con otras naciones); y a nivel interior, los canadienses han preferido un consenso nacional. En cambio, "ahora" Canadá se libera de autolimitaciones y consensos, y actúa de forma mucho más directa por su propia cuenta. Más al estilo de EEUU, y menos al de los países escandinavos.

(Nota: el texto es de 2014. Hoy en día, el Primer Ministro de Canadá es Justin Trudeau).